# C++ hook process and show status

Tags: c++, dll, hook

Ok so I am learning C++ slowly. I am familiar with all the console syntax and everything, but now I'm moving on to windows programming. Now what im trying to do, is create a DLL that I inject into a process, so it's hooked in. All I want the C++ application to do, is have text in it, that says "Hooked" if it's successfully injected, and an error if something wrong happened. Or even if I can do it without a DLL, Just open an executable, and when the certain process I'm trying to hook is opened, the status is changed to "Hooked". Also I have a safaribooksonline.com account so if there is any good reads you would recommend, just write it down. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be looking at this backwards. In C/C++ an application 'pulls' a DLL in rather than having a DLL 'injected' into an application. Typically for plugins/hooks, there is some mechanism to inform an application of a DLL's availability (often just its presence in a specific directory) and a configuration file or some other logic is used to instruct the application to explicitly load the library, extract a function or two, and call them.

For Windows programming, I'd suggest doing a search for examples of the LoadLibrary() API call. You'll likely find [a tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c9855) or two on how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If by "hooked" you mean, "have my DLL run in that processes' address space", you want [`CreateRemoteThread()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682437(VS.85).aspx). This is fairly advanced and difficult to debug, because your bugs make the other program crash. It's how a lot of malware works, by the way.

If you mean "have my DLL get notified of activity in the other process", you want [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to inject as soon as the application starts? You can do that with Microsoft's Detours `DetourCreateProcessWithDll()`. Example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/funapihook.aspx).